# Does readFile opens a file under the hood, reads it's content using `.read` method and closes it

Tags: node.js

Node.js has two ways how to read a file (apart from using streams):

1) Open, read, close

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = __dirname + "/foo.txt";
fs.stat(path, function (error, stats) {
    // opening a file
    fs.open(path, "r", function (error, fd) {
        const buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
        // reading a file
        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function (error, bytesRead, buffer) {
            const data = buffer.toString("utf8");
            console.log(data);
            // closing a file
            fs.close(fd, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.error("close error: " + error.message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

2) readFile

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = __dirname + "/foo.txt";
fs.readFile(path, "utf8", function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.error("read error: " + error.message);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Am I right to assume that under the hood `readFile` still opens a file, reads its content and closes the file? Adding a reference to particular lines in sources is welcome.

Comment: FYI, you should probably be doing `fs.open -> fs.fstat -> fs.read -> fs.close` instead of `fs.stat -> fs.open -> fs.read -> fs.close`. That way the file cannot be unlinked in between getting the stats and opening the file descriptor.

Comment: @idbehold, thanks for your comment. This is an example from the book `Pro Node.js Developers`. Maybe they were doing `fs.stat` first to find out if it's a file or a folder, although this is not reflected in the code.

Comment: I agree that is what they were likely trying to do, but it is still better to to `fs.open -> fs.fstat` to check for file/folder/symlink/etc and then `fs.close` if the path wasn't a file. It's more complicated, but it *will* prevent the race condition where the path is pointing to a file at the point you called `fs.stat` and then either gets unlinked or renamed or replaced by the time you call `fs.open` afterward.

Comment: @idbehold, yes, thanks a lot for your help